# Why do I get 90.370+1.180+8.450 = 100.00000000000001 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, addition, parsefloat

I am trying to add three numbers "90.370", "1.180" and 8.450. And I get the result as 100.00000000000001. when I slightly change these values I am getting exact 100. Can someone please explain me this.
90.370+1.180+8.450 = 100.00000000000001
90.350+1.200+8.450 = 100
[image shows above addition operation in chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLuTB.png)

How to correct this and get the correct value in all the cases.